# Deny read permissions on an Organisational Unit within a Domain via Powershell

Tags: powershell, directory

I'm writing a powershell script that would deny read permissions to a desired list of OU's.

I've been able to add the group to the OU's in question however I am unable to give these groups deny read permissions on the OU's they have been added to.

Can't seem to find anything about this via google.

Cheers

Comment: Deny read to what?

Comment: Don't think you tried very hard as the first results page google for "powershell ad ou permissions" contains [Modifying Permissions on an Active Directory OU with Powershell](https://sysjam.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/modifying-permissions-on-an-active-directory-with-powershell/)